# Understanding a Select loop for receiving UDP messages and opening TCP sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

Hi I'm working a project for a networking class where we are creating nodes in a network that receive messages from a control app via udp and then create tcp connections with other nodes. The basic order goes: 1) control manager sends udp message to node A telling it to connnect to node B 2) node A receives udp message and forwards the udp message to node B 3) node B receives the udp message, randomly choses a port number, opens a listening tcp socket on that port, and sends a udp message back to A with the port number 4) node A receives the udp message and opens a connection on that tcp port to node B.

Basically, I want to loop on udp messages received and jump to my message parsing function while at the same time, looping for tcp connections. That part seems simple enough but I don't really understand how to add listening sockets to the file descriptor list. The following code is what i put together and im wondering if the basic structure looks correct? I don't really understand how to create listening tcp socket and add it to the fd list?

```
SOCKET udpsock;
udpsock = initudp(port); //setup udp socket
SOCKET tcpsock;
FD_ZERO(&rdsocks);

max = udpsock + 1;
while(1)
{
    SOCKET temp;

    FD_SET(udpsock,&rdsocks);//setup udp macros
    FD_SET(tcpsock,&rdsocks);

    if( select(max,&rdsocks,NULL,NULL,NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        perror("Select error");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    for(temp = 0; temp<=max;temp++) // loop on TCP sockets
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(temp,&rdsocks))
        {
            printf("Socket %d is ready \n",temp);
            // process tcp messages
        }

    }
    if(FD_ISSET(udpsock,&rdsocks)) // udp connection, parse control message
    {
        int ret = 0;
        res = recvfrom(udpsock, buff,sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr*)&udpclient,lenaddr);
        //process udp message, setup tcp connection here if requested and add to file descriptor list?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `FD_ZERO()` on each loop iteration before calling `FD_SET()` and `select()`. Also, don't add a TCP socket to the `fd_set` until after you attempt to connect it first.  Keep a list of the TCP sockets you create, so you can re-add them to the `fd_set` on each loop iteration.

Try something like this:

```
udpsock = initudp(port); //setup udp socket

std::vector<SOCKET> tcpsocks;
SOCKET tcpsock;

while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&rdsocks);
    FD_SET(udpsock, &rdsocks);
    max = udpsock;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < tcpsocks.size(); ++i)
    {
        tcpsock = tcpsocks[i];
        FD_SET(tcpsock, &rdsocks);

        if( tcpsock > udpsock )
            max = tcpsock;
    }

    if( select(max+1, &rdsocks, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        perror("Select error");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < tcpsocks.size(); ++i) // loop on TCP sockets
    {
        tcpsock = tcpsocks[i];            
        if( FD_ISSET(tcpsock, &rdsocks) )
        {
            printf("Socket %d is ready \n", tcpsock);
            // process tcp message
        }
    }

    if( FD_ISSET(udpsock, &rdsocks) )
    {
        int ret = 0;
        res = recvfrom(udpsock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&udpclient, lenaddr);
        // process udp message...
        if( setup tcp connection is requested )
        {
            tcpsock = ...;
            if( tcpsock != INVALID_SOCKET )
                tcpsocks.push_back(tcpsock);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you created listening TCP socket ([`socket(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html), [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html), [`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html)), mark it non-blocking with [`setsockopt(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html), and add it to the read-set for [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html).

When it becomes "readable" it means you have client connection pending, call [`accept(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept.2.html). Add the new connected socket to the read-set too.

You might want to keep a list/hash/whatever of these client sockets since read-set has to be re-initialized before each call to [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) and to compute its first argument (max fd).

<sub>Note 0: I reference Linux manual pages here, but the logic is pretty much cross-platform. You can find Windows references on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/e).</sub>
<sub>Note 1: Windows [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IGNORES its first argument.</sub>